# How do I import a stylesheet scoped and deep targeting child component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that I would like to pass styles to. Is there any way of passing in the following scoped and deep to the child component?

```
<style scoped src="../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"></style>
```

As it is now, it only applies to the parent component. I would like to avoid pasting this into every child component that needs this, and I do not want this stylesheet to globally affect the application.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible with Vue.